# Jquery if checkbox is ticked then hide the parent li

Tags: jquery, hide, parent

Im trying to get it so on page load if a checbox is ticked, then it will hide the surrounding li.

```
<ul class="packages">

  <li class="wrap">
       <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  </li>

   <li class="wrap">
       <input type="checkbox">
  </li>

</ul>

<button onclick="runCode()">Button</button>

<script>
function runCode(){
           if ($('.packages input').attr('checked')) {
           $(this).parent().hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sooooo run `runCode` when the page loads. What's the issue?

Comment: Ive tried it on page load so added a button for testing in case it was that. I console logged inside the function and it is triggering, just not hiding the input.

Comment: @Andreas by div i meant the input.

Comment: Why would it hide an input? `this` in `runCode` is the `window`. And the `if` condition won't work either for individual checkboxes.

Comment: @Andreas sorry have updated the code to avoid confusion. What i am actually wanting to achieve is to hide the parent li element. Ive tried .parent().hide() and that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simplify it into :

`$('.packages input').is(':checked').parent().hide();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="packages">

  <li class="wrap" style="display: none;">
       <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  </li>

   <li class="wrap">
       <input type="checkbox">
  </li>

</ul>
<button id="button-cl">Button</button>




$('#button-cl').on('click', function(e){
    $( "input:checked" ).parent().hide();

})
```